# WPF Combobox property IsTextSearchEnabled - how to not allow own text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a Combobox in a DataGrid which allows IsTextSearchEnabled. This works but the user is allowed to put their own text when the item is not found in the combobox. Is there a property that will stop this, or what can I do to stop the user adding their own text?

The xaml

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Types, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                    AncestorType=Window}}"
                                  x:Name="cmbDeploymentEditType"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  SelectedValue="Type"
                                  Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                                  IsEditable="True">
                 </ComboBox>
              </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps an event handler to OnLostFocus or some OnSubmit event which clears the combobox item if it's not in the source collection?

Comment: I was thinking this as a last resort, basically if xaml couldn't do it.  Not looking good! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can handle this, you can use a control that stops this like the [XamMultiColumnComboEditor](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/xamMultiCCE_Using.html) with CustomValueEnteredAction setting. Or you could do [validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714593.aspx) to enforce the rule you want.